# Project Euler: Summation of primes... Why won't this work?

Tags: c++, project, solution

I keep getting the wrong answer of 1179908154. At first I blamed it on my summation variable being type int, rather than long. I gave it long type but I get the same answer. Thoughts?

```
// Project Euler

// Problem 10

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void main() 
{

int p = 3;
long sum = 2;
bool isPrime;
for (p; p < 2000000; p++)
{
    isPrime = true;

    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(static_cast<double>(p)); i++) // cast into double for sqrt function
    {
        if (p % i == 0)
        {
            isPrime = false;
            break;

        }
    }
    if (isPrime == true)
    {
        cout << p << endl; // show each prime
        sum += p; // add prime to sum 
    }

}
cout << sum << endl; // show sum 

system("pause");
```

}

Comment: I bet `sizeof(long)` is 4 in your implementation. 32 bits is too small to hold the sum.

Comment: This was correct. Thank you! I used long long instead.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe on your platform the long is not enough to hold the value too. Try a long long instead.

Answer (score 2):

Do not write prime numbers generator by yourself, it's really not easy.
Just use this http://cr.yp.to/primegen.html , it's really good enough for project euler.

Comment: I don't think the purpose of Project Euler is to be easy :) It is supposed to challenge you until you get that A-ha! moment.

Answer (score 0):

When putting the bounds on your for loop, you should check numbers up until sqrt(p) + 1. You can get floating point errors when calculating the square root (it might underestimate it slightly), so it's possible that some potential factors are not checked in the loop.

Comment: doubles have 53 bits of precision, so can represent 53 bit integers exactly. int are (normally) 32-bits. So casting to double is not a problem.

Comment: I tried running this code and it will not run as-is. The compiler says to change the type of main to int, which I did, and I got rid of that system("pause") at the end because I'm not why it's even there. Anyway, when I run I get a different answer than 1179908154. Are you sure you're not running an older version of the code?

Comment: Actually, the better way of doing it is `i*i <= p` because squaring is faster than square-rooting and there are no floating point answers.

Comment: @SparkleStilettos What answer do you get?